# MVC Routing regex parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this route set up:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Competition",
    "{comp_id}/Competition/",
    new { controller = "Competition", action = "Index" },
    new { comp_id = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$" }
    );
```

The regex is supposed to allow 6 character competition ids that can have alphanumeric characters and is not case sensitive.
What I would like to do is allow the id to be greater than 3 characters long with no restriction in length.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic regex. Use `{3,}` instead of `{6}` if you mean that it needs to be 3 or more characters, or `{4,}` if you mean that it has to be greater than 3.